# How to have multiple input files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I need to pass multiple input files to a command line app, but when I do

```
test --input k1.toml k2.toml k3.toml --project xxx --username xxx
```

with this code

```
'use strict'
var minimist = require('minimist')

var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  string: ['input', 'project', 'username',],
  boolean: ['help'],
  alias: { i: 'input' },
  unknown: function () { console.log('Unkown argument') }
})

console.log(argv)
```

I get

```
Unkown argument
Unkown argument
{ _: [ 'k2.toml', 'k3.toml' ],
  help: false,
  input: '1.toml',
  i: 'k1.toml',
  project: 'xxx',
  username: 'xxx' }
```

where I would have expected `input` to be an array of the filenames. Here it thinks the filenames are arguments and therefore triggers `unknown: function ()`.

## Question

What is the correct way to pass multiple input files?

I am willing to use something different than `minimist` if that is a limitation of `minimist`.